# Can I modify the content of the default "main.rs" file in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When you use `cargo new <name>`, cargo creates a new project with a "main.rs" and other files. In the "main.rs" file is always written

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, World!");
}
```

Is it possible to modify the default content of the "main.rs" file? If it is possible, how?

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to modify the "default content" ? Do you have a (very good) reason for doing that ?

Answer (score 2):

No, the initial file contents for `main.rs` (if creating a binary) or `lib.rs` (if creating a library) are [hardcoded into Cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/754a5bfbaa9b5c677e0d96ca7edc17051bf311e1/src/cargo/ops/cargo_new.rs#L804-L827).

You could try using [`cargo-generate`](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-generate) to be able to generate Cargo projects from a Git repo template. See [its documentation](https://cargo-generate.github.io/cargo-generate/index.html) for information about how to use it.